# Get remaining time of Timer in Dart

Tags: dart

How to get the remaining time in seconds of Timer from `'dart:async'` in Dart?

I have a countdown timer and at some point I want to get the remaining time in seconds. How do I do this in dart?

```
_endTimer = Timer(Duration(seconds: totalRemainingTimeInSeconds), () {
  _end();
});
```

Comment: You don't. You have to use a `Timer.periodic` and keep track of remaining time yourself, or find a package that does this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot get that from a `Timer`.

What you can do is to start a [`Stopwatch`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html) at the same time as the timer.

If you need to do things along the way, they can check the stopwatch to see the duration so far. To update a countdown timer, I'd probably use a combination of `Stopwatch` to count time and `Timer.periodic` to update the UI occasionally, and either have the periodic timer check whether the countdown is over, or have a single `Timer` to react on timeout.